# Using CookieParam annotation with Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use the `javax.ws.rs.CookieParam` annotation to grab a cookie from the HTTP request to a method on my controller.

```
@Override
public void cookieTest( @CookieParam("testToken") String testCookie, HttpServletRequest request ) {

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for( Cookie cookie : cookies ) {
        if( cookie.getName().equals( "testToken" ) ) {
            System.out.println( "found testToken" );
        }
    }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No parameter name specified for argument of type [java.lang.String], and no parameter name information found in class file either.
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.getRequiredParameterName(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:729)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestParam(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:488)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:348)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
... 67 more
```

The controller does have an interface, but I added the `CookieParam` annotation in both places with the correct name. If I remove the testCookie parameter, I can iterate through the `request.getCookies()` and see that the cookie does exist. Is there a step I'm missing?

I'm using Spring 3 and Java 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong annotation. Use @CookieValue instead https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/CookieValue.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of one of my controller methods that makes use of a cookie :

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, 
        @CookieValue(value = "aCookie", defaultValue = "someRandomValue") String aValue)
```